# What does the masculine nominative "einer" represent in "Sieh mal einer an"?

Tags: sentence-structure

This may be just a fixed expression, but I'm curious what  the masculine nominative "einer" represents. Is there another similar expression that uses a mysterious  masculine nominative like this?

Comment: It's not feminine dative, it's a masculine nominative - [Indefinitpronomen](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/ein#Indefinitpronomen).

Answer (score 2):

As [Eller](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/18610/eller) commented:

This is not a feminine dative, it is a masculine nominative. Because it is a [Indefinitpronomen](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/ein#Indefinitpronomen).

Feminine nominative would be "eine".

In case you are female, you *could* say "Sieh mal eine an.", it is just very uncommon as it is an idiom known with "einer".

This idiom "sieh mal einer an" could be translated with ["What do you say..."](https://www.dict.cc/?s=Na%20sieh%20mal%20einer%20an) or "look what we have here" or "[Looky here!](https://dict.tu-chemnitz.de/dings.cgi?service=deen&opterrors=0&optpro=0&query=sieh%20mal%20einer%20an&iservice=)".

So the "einer" refers to you as the speaker himself, speaking in third person of yourself.

Using this idiom you express some kind of surprise / amazement / astonishment. It could be meant sarcastic, ironic or "real" - and many nuances in between.

So I have to deny an answer to your question about another example of "mysterious feminine", because this is none.

Comment: A common Englisch idiom is also "Now, look at that".

Comment: I don't think this refers to yourself but to anyone who would take a look.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence "Sieh mal einer an." is more like a colloquial expression. 
The "einer" is not feminine, it's either masculine or even neutral (meaning both men and women).

The full expression means something like "**How about that ...**". 
I don't think you can really analyse the meaning of the words separately, because it's an idiomatic phrase and therefore would not work anymore, if you teared it apart.